# aarch64 cache flushing/invalidating an userspace virtual address with "DC CIVAC" instruction in kernel space

Tags: linux, caching, arm64

In aarch64 + Linux environment, I want flush or invalidate an userspace virtual address. I passed the userspace virtual address to kernel space driver, and use the "DC CIVAC <virtual_address>" assembly instruction to flush and invalidate the cache.

My question is if it is a valid way to flush and invalidate the cache? I did a simple test, and it seems work correctly. But what will happen if there is an exactly the same userspace virtual address for two different processes (and assuming both virtual addresses are in the cache line)? Does the "DC CIVAC <virtual_address>" assembly instruction in kernel space recognize which process the virtual address belongs to and choose to flush the expected cache line?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 translation tables pointer by addresses in registers `TTBR0_EL1`, `TTBR1_EL1` (note one register is '0', other is '1').

One table is used for process in user space memory mapping, and other for kernel memory mapping.

So once in kernel space (EL1) there are 2 active translation tables, and `DC CIVAC <virtual_address>` could provide virtual address in any of this tables.

> My question is if it is a valid way to flush and invalidate the cache?

That should be fine. Data cache is physically tagged. That means that 'virt addr' parameter is translated to physical address first via translation tables. If translation failed, exception would be generated. Since you don't see anything like that, I'd say that data cache maintain instruction works.

> But what will happen if there is an exactly the same userspace virtual
> address for two different processes

Nothing wrong would happen. As a matter of fact userspace addresses are same for a processes (at least at a point when process starts).
Each user space process has it's own memory mapping table, and kernel set right table for process when doing thread/process switching. And as I told earlier, `DC CIVAC` at first resolves virtual-to-physical address. So even though **virtual** addresses are same, underlying **physical** addresses are different.

There is a catch, I need to mention. That's possible to map same physical memory region to different processes. In that case it's same physical address, but each process would have different virtual addresses for that same region (virtual addresses could be same by accident, but that does not matter, virt-to-phys resolution done over different translation tables).

If that's a case, cache maintain instruction would affect different processes (IMHO, never tried that case in practice).

Comment: Thanks guy! I think the key information is:
| So once in kernel space (EL1) there are 2 active translation tables, and DC CIVAC <virtual_address> could provide virtual address in any of this tables.

It means the hardware will use both page table provided in `TTBR0_EL1` and `TTBR1_EL1`. I used to think the `DC` instruction in kernel space will only use kernel's own page table, but not user process's one.

Comment: Kernel has to have access to user space memory to serve service calls to start with. Think for example, app going to read/write file. So it's allocate data buffer in user space and doing service call to kernel to read/write. Kernel would not be able to access user data to write into file or fill buffer with data fetched from file.